# How to calculate a point between two angled lines based on distance from the lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Please take a look at the picture below for the diagram reference:

[image: Irregular pentagon with lengths and angles]

I am trying to calculate the point where it is perfectly 3.3 cm vertically from the 44.52 cm line AND 5.5 cm horizontally from the 12 cm line

(I'm using rhinoceros to model this, but the solution doesn't need to be via rhinoceros, can be any way)

Would really appreciate any help to achieve this!

Comment: While pictures can help to bridge over ambiguities in a description of the assumptions, a rigorous "calculation" must proceed from conditions formulated in mathematical expressions.  I can probably make the image visible in your Question, but you should try to articulate what the image says.  See [this introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I showed this diagram to my brother who is colourblind to grey. He could make out nothing.

Comment: If you temporarily draw a line 3.3cm below the long one, and another 5.5cm to the left of the short line, their intersection is your desired point. But, are you sure you don't want the point to be at 3.3cm and 5.5cm from the lines? I.e. not measured horizontally and vertically, but perpendicular to the lines measured from?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with analytic geometry, which is using algebra, especially graphing in the Cartesian plane, to solve geometry problems. We'll also need a little trigonometry, since you give some angles.

Let's place that figure on the Cartesian plane. We'll place the origin $(0,0)$ at the top corner of your figure. The $44.52$ line segment goes through the origin and has the angle of inclination $31.50°$, so its slope is $\tan 31.50°$. Your desired point is $3.30$ below that, so it is on the line with the same slope and $y$-intercept $-3.30$, namely

$$y=(\tan 31.50°)x-3.30$$

The $12.00$ line segment goes through the origin and has the angle of inclination $-43.50°$, so its slope is $\tan -43.50°$. Your desired point is $5.50$ to the left of that, so it is on the line with the same slope and $x$-intercept $-5.50$, namely

$$y=(\tan -43.50°)(x+5.50)$$

Solve those two simultaneous equations. The value of $x$ will be the distance to the right your desired point is from the top point: a negative value of $x$ means your point is actually to the left. The value of $y$ will be the distance up your desired point is from the top point: a negative value of $y$ means your point is actually down.

I'll leave the equation solving to you. Let me know if you have trouble with that. Those tangents means the values of $x$ and $y$ will be irrational numbers. You can decide if the exact values are needed or if good approximations will suffice.